# How to sent messege in blogger?

Tags: javascript, html, alert, blogger

I want to show new visitor an alert in blogger. The alert have to be shown only for the first time. Is cookies help for it. How to use cookies in blogger. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

you should put [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

```
var first = localStorage.getItem("first");
if(!first){
  localStorage.setItem("first", true);
  alert("welcome!");
};
```